# Discrete Fourier transform in Distribution sense

Tags: fourier-analysis, distribution-theory, harmonic-analysis

When we describe the Fourier transform, we first start with nice functions $S(R^n)$ and then extend the operator continuously to a bigger space $S'(R^n)$, which is the space called tempered distribution. Similarly, there should be a counterpart of the process for discrete Fourier transform or Bloch Transform. Is there any reference for such theory?